# Django: Get for hidden field 2 values

Tags: javascript, python, django

My `request.POST` looks like `'hidden': ['testtest', ''],`, but i want to get`'hidden': ['testtest'],`. What could be the reason for it?

`forms.py`:

```
hidden = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=50, widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'id': 'hidden'}))
```

I use javascript to emit the hidden field a value.

```
$('#id_field1').keyup(function() {
    var group_name = $("#id_field1").val();
    $("#hidden").val(group_name);
});
```

The problem is that I get for `request.POST['hidden']` the empty string back.
I know I can use `request.POST.getlist('hidden')`, but I want to understand why I do get 2 values back.

Comment: Check your generated html - if you have more than one field with `nsme="hidden"`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that the csrf_token fileds have also the `name="hidden"` attribute.

Comment: @Udi Maybe you should make that an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simply that I had two times fields with the attribute `name="hidden"` at my `html` file.